# VS Code Bash calls to Azure not authenticated

Tags: bash, azure, azure-rbac

When trying to create a storage account in azure from VS Code's Bash Terminal, I get the following error:

```
error retrieving default location: The client '' with object id '' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over scope '' or the scope is invalid. 
If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

After successfully logging into Azure using az login, I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time past, I was able to run my bash scripts without issues. I ran AZ login again and changed to my subscription. I did all of this before, but I believe it worked this time because the previous session timed out. Previously when I logged into that session I didn't have the necessary permissions and logging in again without previously logging out did not refresh my permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The error means your logged user account/service principal as mentioned in the error does not have enough permission,
to solve the issue, navigate to your `subscription` in the azure portal -> add it with a role e.g. `Contributor` like below.

**Note:** To add the role, your account logged in the portal need to be the `Owner` or `User Access Administrator` of the subscription.

[image]

Comment: But if I am logged into the azure portal I can perform these actions. Same user.

Comment: @kevin Could you check what is your role in the subscription?

Comment: the role is the same in both environments.

Comment: @kevin I know that, please tell me what is the name of the role, and please provide the complete script you used to create the storage account.